# LINQ DataLoadOptions.loadwith

Tags: linq

This is the code I have for loading my data entities.

```
DataLoadOptions dlo = new DataLoadOptions();
dlo.LoadWith<msPlaylistItem>(m => m.tbMedia);
dlo.LoadWith<tbMedia>(a => a.tbArtists);
dlo.LoadWith<msNote>(n => n.tbMedia.msNotes);
db.LoadOptions = dlo;
```

**dlo.LoadWith(n => n.tbMedia.msNotes);**  This is the line I am having a problem with.  This is the error  "The expression specified must be of the form p.A, where p is the parameter and A is a property or field member."

What I am trying to do is load the notes that are related to the each tbMedia object.

Comment: i made this change and I am getting the same error

dlo.LoadWith<tbMedia>(t => t.msNotes.Where(n => n.MediaId==n.tbMedia.id));

Answer (score 0):

this is the correct line

```
dlo.AssociateWith <tbMedia>(t => t.msNotes.Where(n => n.MediaId == n.tbMedia.id));
```